# wpdp update is not working when a form is posted. But can open directly

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to update a custom table row.

Here is my form's code (page-vehicles.php)

```
<form action="<?php echo home_url( "update" ); ?>" method="post">
     <input type="number" name="id">
     <input type="number" name="number">
     <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

When I submit the form to (page-update.php) it shows a 404 error. But if I open the page (page-update.php) directly it shows the page (without 404 error).

What am I doing wrong here? :(

Comment: actually, the same method (posting to a page) worked for inserting a record into a custom table. but it is not working when I am trying to update the record

Answer (score 0):

You said the custom page where the update needs to happen is page-update.php but you are posting the form to `form.action = "http://novits.com/5050/vedit";` Change the action to the proper link.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @AmitJoshi, I tried that and the result is same. I have edited the question to explain my issue shortly. once again thanks a lot for the help

Comment: is it something like, i have to make a function instead of posting into a page?

Comment: `home_url( "update" );` is posting to yourdomain.com/update/. As @AmitJoshi says, change the action to the proper link for page-update.php